# Issue with Bluetooth entitlement (ExternalAccessory) on iOS 10.0+

Tags: bluetooth, xamarin.ios, ios10, entitlements, external-accessory

Everytime I try to list connected bluetooth accessories via ExternalAccessory SDK on iOS 10.0+ (native or Xamarin) I get the following log message:

```
Couldn't find the "com.apple.private.externalaccessory.showallaccessories" entitlement
```

(Swift)

```
let devices = EAAccessoryManager.shared().connectedAccessories
```

(Xamarin.iOS)

```
var devices = EAAccessoryManager.SharedAccessoryManager.ConnectedAccessories;
```

---

My Info.plist looks like:

`<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>external-accessory</string>
        <string>bluetooth-peripheral</string>
        <string>bluetooth-central</string>
    </array>`

`<key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
    <string>BT</string>`

and sample UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols

`<key>UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.getpebble.public</string>
    </array>`

I'm using automatic signing in Xcode, problem occurs only on iOS 10.0+ (both native and Xamarin), on < 10.0 there's no such problem.

---

What's more, I'm able to get connected devices list despite this issue, but I'm unable to write\read stream (I assume because of the entitlement):

```
ERROR - /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/ExternalAccessory/ExternalAccessory-353/EAOutputStream.m:-[EAOutputStream write:maxLength:] - 283 failed to write because stream does not have space available
```

---

I've checked 3rd party libraries ([pebble](https://github.com/pebble/pebble-ios-sdk) and [iZettle](https://github.com/iZettle/sdk-ios) that also use ExternalAccessory SDK and I was also getting the `com.apple.private.externalaccessory.showallaccessories` problem.

Do I missed something? Does anyone know the solution? Thanks!